# Error using QGIS 3.2.2 Warp (Reproject) tool with custom coordinate system

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, gdalwarp

I'm using the QGIS Warp (Reproject) tool to reproject a raster from WGS84 to a Lambert Conformal Conic custom projection in QGIS 3.2.2. The call to the GDAL/OGR console is the following:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=lcc  +lat_1=13.31666666666667  +lat_2=14.25  +lat_0=13.783333  +lon_0=-89 +x_0=500000 +y_0=295809.184 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,125,194,0,0,0,0 +wktext" -r near -ot Int16 -of GTiff C:/n13_w090_1arc_v3.tif "C:/Users/HP COREi5/Documents/n13_w090_1arc_v3_nad27.tif"
```

The result I get is the following:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Warp (reproject)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 1, 'INPUT' : 'C:/n13_w090_1arc_v3.tif', 'MULTITHREADING' : 
False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/HP 
COREi5/Documents/n13_w090_1arc_v3_nad27.tif', 'RESAMPLING' : 0, 'SOURCE_CRS' 
: None, 'TARGET_CRS' : 'USER:100057', 'TARGET_EXTENT' : None, 
'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_RESOLUTION' : None }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_1=13.31666666666667 +lat_2=14.25 
+lat_0=13.783333 +lon_0=-89 
+x_0=500000 +y_0=295809.184 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs 
+towgs84=0,125,194,0,0,0,0 
+wktext" -r near -ot Int16 -of GTiff C:/n13_w090_1arc_v3.tif "C:/Users/HP 
COREi5/Documents/n13_w090_1arc_v3_nad27.tif"
GDAL command output:


FAILURE: No target filename specified.

Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]

[-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"] [-novshiftgrid]

[-order n | -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]

[-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]

[-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]

[-ovr level|AUTO|AUTO-n|NONE] [-wo "NAME=VALUE"] [-ot Byte/Int16/...] [-wt 
Byte/Int16]

[-srcnodata "value [value...]"] [-dstnodata "value [value...]"] -dstalpha

[-r resampling_method] [-wm memory_in_mb] [-multi] [-q]

[-cutline datasource] [-cl layer] [-cwhere expression]

[-csql statement] [-cblend dist_in_pixels] [-crop_to_cutline]

[-of format] [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-overwrite]

[-nomd] [-cvmd meta_conflict_value] [-setci] [-oo NAME=VALUE]*

[-doo NAME=VALUE]*

srcfile* dstfile



Available resampling methods:

near (default), bilinear, cubic, cubicspline, lanczos, average, mode, max, 
min, med, Q1, Q3.

Execution completed in 0.18 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/HP 
COREi5/Documents/n13_w090_1arc_v3_nad27.tif, 'createOptions': 
{'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/HP 
COREi5/Documents/n13_w090_1arc_v3_nad27.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log 
Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the 
execution of the algorithm.
```

If I type the same GDAL/OGR call in the OSGeo4W Shell it runs without problems.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround in QGIS?

Comment: Most likely the whitespace in the path is the problem. Try with a different output folder.

Comment: I tried with a path with no spaces and the result is the same,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is related to the custom coordinate system I´m using. I had an error in the definition of my CRS, with a newline character that didn't cause problems when reprojecting vector files, but caused problems when running a GDAL tool. Thanks to @AndreJ for testing the tool with a custom CRS.

Comment: Related bug report: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19855

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ. It was a problem with my custom CRS definition.